# Can't set background image in CSS on webpage

Tags: html, css, web

I can see the background on my website locally but when it upload it to the ftp server...its lost. i cant see the background.

```
body {
background: url("../images/coffee-bg.jpg");
background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: image path is correct ?

Comment: ` background-image: url("../images/coffee-bg.jpg");`

Comment: Last time I was deploying an application with FTP, I found that it took some time for the image to load since I didn't optimize it. How about checking your inspect and see if the image came in successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your image path, your path is incorrect. try adding ftp ip wt